# Git not asking to commit before switching branches

Tags: git

If I run git status:

```
# On branch new-media
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   modified:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Then I checkout the master: with `git checkout master`

```
M   .gitignore
M   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Previously, git stopped me from checkout other branches, prompting me to either stash or commit the changes I've made on the current one.  Now, it no longer does so.

Comment: I'm sure it never did behave that way. This behavior is intentional. Could it be you are confusing this with changes that have been added to the index and switching branches?

Comment: you need to have at least one commit on either branches to tell git that these branches have different history. then git will start to ask you when you have uncommitted changes and you're trying to switch branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git switches branches with a dirty working directory just fine if the changed files are the same on both branches. If not, it will stop you. You can override this behavior with the `-m` flag.

See

- http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/
- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html

Comment: the first link points to https://gogopdf.com/blog/Working-with-PDFs-on-Repositories

Answer (score 1):

It only prevents you from switching branches with uncommitted changes when those changes conflict with files in the other branch. If Git can switch cleanly, it will do so without prompting you.

Answer (score 1):

It should prevent the branch checkout (prompting for a stash or commit) ***if*** there had been another change to those same files on the branch that you were attempting to check out.  But if there were no differences between branches to those files, then it should always allow the checkout.

I agree with pmr, you're seeing the "normal" behavior now, and have seen the "conflict" behavior before.